# how to access youtube raw video file and play it in android youtube api

Tags: android, video, android-intent, youtube, youtube-api

i want to display all the videos uploaded by a user, say cnn, 
in my own android app, i will have a webview, and when user clicks on this video (cnn), it will play that particular youtube video in  android's native video player, once video finishes, it will return to my app (webview where user lastly clicked)
my question is, which part of the google youtube data api should i feed to the intent? using the example below?

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_understanding_video_feeds#Understanding_Video_Entries

can someone give me a CONCRETE example, no abbreviation or whatsoever, a link i should put in the intent?
i am confused because examples i found has .mp4 extension etc, which android will understand the intent that a video is requested to play.
but in the link provided above, there is no link to the raw file, i.e. no URI ends with .mp4

please help

Answer (score 0):

By going thorough the documentation about youtube api and testing the [demo App](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/) i think in-order make a app using youtube-api need

1) [Developer key](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol)

2)Phone installed with latest version of youtube application (i think Actually youtube-api use some supports of youtube app to play video)

3)By using this api video will stay inside your app. but it use support from youtube app to play video

**Note:-** if am wrong Correct me